# How to detect that my scrolling is lagging in iOS (UIKit and SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit, scrollview

I want to find a way to detect in production if users are experimenting lagging when scrolling, and log that in my analytics object.

Is there a way to detect that in code?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in this year (2022) WWDC [Track down hangs with Xcode and on-device detection](https://Track%20down%20hangs%20with%20Xcode%20and%20on-device%20detection)
conference they explain how to track this in production.

It's not a solution only for scrollview but for all hangs in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CADisplayLink. Measure approximately like this:

On each displayLink tick, you need to save displayLink.timestamp(previousTimestamp).

```
hitch = displayLink.timestamp - previousTimestamp - 1 / 60
```

If hitch > 0, then you haven't finished within 1/60 of a frame, and your scroll is lagging.
It is worth mentioning that this calculation will not work on promotion screens, so you will need to write more complex logic.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think there's an effective way to do that. (Technically you could start a timer when the scrolling starts, measure the distance scrolled, check if the time suits the distance - if so, there's no lag, and then send a report, but sheesh that ain't worth it) App Store Connect offers crash reports from TestFlight, but I'm afraid that's as far as you can get with that.

The best way would be to get some (human) testers. You can send me the TestFlight link and I'll try it out if it helps!